# Wifi Autologin with Greasemonkey

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I need some help. My dormitory not allowed to use private internet and they give me only shared wifi user. So It's very annoyed that wifi will automatically wipe out any session and need to login again every 4-5 hour plus due electrical is not well here randomly surge and it make session lost and need to login again too. (Seem like they don't have UPS for login server) I heard about greasemonkey can handle some kind of job like this so I get that and find a code and try modified it, Badly I never work with Javascript before (Just beginner with C) I took 3 day and it seem to be not work at all. So any solution for me? I need a code that check every 15-30 minute to monitor my wifi session if it time out and redirect to login page then click a submit button (No need to enter User/Pass because I make Firefox remember that and auto fill it)

Here's login page form script

> ```
> <form method="post" action="http://192.168.99.254:8000/">
> <input name="redirurl" type="hidden" value="http://www.google.co.th">
> <table align="center">
>    <tr><td>Username:</td><td><input name="auth_user" type="text"></td></tr>
>    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input name="auth_pass" type="password"></td></tr>
>    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
>    <tr>
>      <td colspan="2">
>   <center><input name="accept" type="submit" value="Continue"></center>
>      </td>
>    </tr>
> </table>
> </center>
> </form>
> ```

Another info is I try this but it's not work, Firefox keep waiting for '192.168.99.254:8000'

> ```
> document.forms[0].submit();
> ```

Thanks you :) sorry for bad english